# Plotting points and functions in one graphic

Tags: plotting

I have this plot:

```
Plot[{0 x, -x, x, -Sqrt[2 - x^2], Sqrt[2 - x^2]}, {x, -3, 3}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Purple}]
```

[image]

Now I want to do the following. I want to plot the points: $(-1,0),(1,0),(0,0),(x,0),(1, \pm 1),(1,\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}),(0, \pm \frac{2}{\sqrt 3}),(0, \pm \sqrt 2)$ in this graphic. I'm able to plot points using `Graphics[Point[{x, y}]`but I would like to plot those point in the same graphic. This is probably really easy, but I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Look `Epilog` in help.

Comment: just Show[ Plot[..] , Graphics[..] ]

Comment: Aah thanks  ! got it

Comment: In the same vein as @george's suggestion: you could use `Show[]` to display the output of `Plot[]` and `ListPlot[]` together.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to george2079 I was able to get what I needed:

```
Data = {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 
   1/Sqrt[3]}, {1, -1/Sqrt[3]}, {0, 2/Sqrt[3]}, {0, -2/Sqrt[3]}, {0, 
   Sqrt[2]}, {0, -Sqrt[2]}}
Show[Plot[{0 x, -x, x, -Sqrt[2 - x^2], Sqrt[2 - x^2]}, {x, -3, 3}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Purple}], Plot[0 x, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}], 
 Graphics[{PointSize[Medium], Blue, Point[Data]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For fun, let's describe the ellipse--which is actually a circle--in polar coordinates and specify the points more simply as complex numbers rather than pairs of reals. And then use David Park's *Presentations* add-on (http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/DrawGraphicsPage.html) in order to draw the whole thing--*without* having to use `PlotStyle`, `Graphics`, or `Show` (at least, not overtly):

```
pts = {1, 1 + I, 1 + I/Sqrt[3], 2 I/Sqrt[3]};
pts = Join[{0}, pts, Conjugate[pts]];
Draw2D[{
        Thick, Purple, PolarDraw[Sqrt[2], {t, 0, 2 Pi}], 
        Thickness[0.0035], Draw[{-x, x}, {x, -3, 3}],
        Black, PointSize[Large], ComplexPoint /@ pts
       }, 
       Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 3]
```

[image]